# SSRS 2017 machineKey deleted on restart

Tags: reporting-services, machinekey

I've implemented the solution from [here](https://codeliteral.wordpress.com/2016/10/05/ssrs-2016-form-authentication/) (with the 2017 equivalents from comments) but i've hit a roadblock and i'm not able to find a solution. The '<'machineKey'>' tag from web.config and from rsportal.exe.config **are deleted after restart** . 
Because of that (i think) after i log in i get a 500 Internal server error. I've searched the logs and found this error :

> Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.UnhandledHttpApplicationException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.UnhandledHttpApplicationException:
>   The report server encountered an unhandled exception in
>   HttpApplication.
>   ---> System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that
>   **machineKey** configuration specifies the same validationKey and
>   validation algorithm.  AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

I've set the machineKey tag in RSPortal.exe.config , web.config and in rsreportserver.config .I've tried deleting the encryption key's and restarting it and it did not help.   Any ideea how to fix this or what is causing it ?

Answer (score 2):

it happened to me as well and was resolved by adding the machine key to rsreportserver.config inside Configuration section right after Dsn element
in the following case:
MachineKey

[image]

Comment: How did you generate the machine key?

Comment: @Rohan https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it is related to the format. Please use the below format

```
<MachineKey 
ValidationKey="BE4663BB11C14E8C7C1DB0A48022D517CB668C65A46174B0C4CFF4D9B7CE2498EA998C4E5A8C15EE5262D5C297479349B2A9783700AB3C1C891B914D12691A0D" 
DecryptionKey="7121FD4D52F0035DBBB113B9E449ED4467CA01DDD26684FF" 
Validation="SHA1" 
Decryption="AES"/>
```